# iPhone Block SMS using xcoding,Private Frameworks whatever

Tags: iphone, xcode, sms, block

this is Nsr..

I need some help about using private frameworks, i have checked almost all the links and articles about PF, but it didn't help me whatsoever. Iv also looked into Github but didn't get  the required answer/result.

I want to build an app regarding iPhone messaging. i want my phone not to recieve any SMS/MMS for a certain time(whenever i launch my app). Iv looked into Chatkit framework, but its not even my Private Framework's folder..

I am a beginner in using private API, actually this is my first time to i dont event know how to add/code/use private API or class dump(no idea what the hack is this). I just want a good guidance as im not able to proceed any further than designing my app right now..

Kindly save your messages about not using private APi's..
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

**For non-Jailbroken iPhone**

*You can intercept the SMS notification, but you can't stop them from going through.*

Here's is What I got for you

**A:** *Core Telephony now lives in Private Frameworks*
**E:** *You can intercept the SMS notification, but you can't stop them from going through.*
**J:** *There is SMS sample code floating around in the jailbreak world. You should be able to google it down pretty easily*
**W:** *It's not possible to disable USSD notifications from a programmatic point of view.*

Please check out [this link](http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/02/when-it-comes-to-the.html)

.

While **For Jailbroken iPhone.**

Please check out How to [react on incoming sms on an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058001/react-on-incoming-sms-on-an-iphone)?

Comment: varma, are you saying its no possible ?

Comment: Check out additional details. May be it can help

Comment: Thanx for you reply, but i need a way out ... anyway that i can block my iphone's signal or anthing that stops my SMS incoming..