# How can i mute incoming text on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I know there is no way to read call/sms record in iOS

But i want to mute incoming text sounds with in my app. This setting seems in ringtone so there may be a solution

Let me know is it possible or not

I found another link but no answer
[How can I mute incoming iPhone text messages programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016443/how-can-i-mute-incoming-iphone-text-messages-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using public APIs, it is not possible.

The link you found is using private APIs, which aren't documented or guaranteed to work the way you'd expect. If you tried to release an App Store app that called a private API, it would be automatically rejected.

Comment: but there are many apps like that in the app store like autosilent?